# Array of pointers to objects returns jibberish

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Good evening,

I've been tasked with a mission to create an array that'll hold all objects in game.
Sadly, all of these objects are created in different places - putting them into an array manually would be tedious - in fact, I would feel better if they were physically in the place where they were created, but with a reference to them stored in an array.. a reference in form of a pointer.

So, this is what I figured out so far, I've done so pointer to every instance of the object is added to the array in constructor as seen below:

```
const int GAME_MAX_ENTS = 65536;
class Object
{
    public:
        static Object* list[GAME_MAX_ENTS];
        char type[64] = "ENT_OBJECT";
        Object();
        ~Object();
};

Object::Object()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GAME_MAX_ENTS; i++)
    {
        if (!list[i])
        {
            list[i] = this;
            break;
        }
    }
}

Object* Object::list[GAME_MAX_ENTS];
```

Now, my issue is - when I'm trying to look through that list and display value of 'type' in a different scope than the one in which object was created, it pops nonsense - I'm assuming it's random memory output.

Here's the portion of me trying to pop proper info:

```
static void OnRender()
{
    //Grid
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    //Draw objects
    for (int i = 0; i < GAME_MAX_ENTS; i++)
    {
        if (Object::list[i])
        {
            Object* obj = Object::list[i];
            printf("%s\n", obj->type);
        }
    }

    [...]
```

.. and to make everything as clear as possible, here's the portion where I created objects - mind you, Tile is just a class inheriting from Object:

```
    static void Initialize()
    {
        [...]

        Tile tile;
        Object obj;
    }
```

I'm fairly certain it's all due to my lack of experience with C++, I'm just a web dev/C# scrub - don't go hard on me ^^

Comment: The `Object obj;` is local to `Initialize`. Even if it registers itself in the pointer array, it still goes out of scope at the end of the function.

Comment: It would be worth adding a destructor to `Object` to remove `this` from the array

Comment: The standard advice for C++ is to use a `std::vector` instead of an array. Then you can just `push_back` new items without having to set a max size or scan for free slots.

Comment: These are very good points, I'll keep that in mind once I get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're creating objects in `Initialize()` that then go out of scope. In C++, you have to manage your own memory (when using pointers). Storing a pointer to an object does not prevent it from being destroyed.

You will need to either store a copy of the objects or explicitly create the objects with `new` and then manage the pointers (or use C++ smart pointers to help you manage them).

Comment: This seems like the answer I was looking for.
Does 'new' keyword prevent destructor from running itself?
I assume it's due to garbage collection?

Comment: Replacing the way I was creating elements with: ```  Tile* tile1 = new Tile();
   Object* obj1 = new Object();``` Worked!

Comment: @Netheous Yes. If you create an object with `new` you have to delete it manually using `delete`. Typically people use `std::unique_ptr` which deletes it automatically.

Comment: @Netheous: In C++ you don't have automatic garbage collection (I'm not counting `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` as "automatic"). If you create a local variable, it will be created on the stack and will be destroyed as soon as it goes out of scope. If you use `new`, then it will be created in the heap and you will need to make sure you call `delete` later to free that memory back up. If you want garbage collection, you need to use something like `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` which explicitly handle garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep pointers to the objects in such way that they are automatically added upon construction and removed upon destruction. One way to do so is to have a `set` of observing pointers:

```
// file object.h
namespace game {
  struct object  // all game objects are derived from this
  {
    static set<const object*> const&list();  // return list of all objects
    virtual draw() const;                    // example of virtual function
    object();                                // only ctor: add this to list
    object(object const&) = delete;          // disable copy ctor of base
    virtual ~object();                       // dtor: remove this from list
  };
}

// file object.cc
#include "object.h"
#include <set>
#include <mutex>
namespace {
  std::mutex protect_object_list;
  std::set<const object*> object_list;
}

std::set<const object*> const& object::list()
{
  return object_list;
}

object::object()
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(protect_object_list);
  object_list.insert(this);
}

object::~object()
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(protect_object_list);
  object_list.erase(this);
}
```

Usage might look like

```
#include "object.h"
namespace game {
  struct tile : object
  {
    void draw() const override;
    tile(position const&pos) : object() { /* ... */ }
    tile(tile const&t) : object() { /* ... */ }
  };

  void draw_objects()
  {
    for(auto const&obj:object::list())
      obj.draw();
  }
}
```

In this way, the objects in `object::list` are ordered by the pointer comparison. If you want another ordering, you may want to use `std::map<size_t,const object*>` and use as key a static counter incremented at construction of an object.